How to change password on ubuntu usb drive
I have a removable usb drive with ubuntu on it. I can't login and need to change password.
I have seen many questions and answer to changing password on host drive but not on usb drive.
I tried following there commands, I can mount the drive but was lost as to how to change user password on that drive.  I always ended up changing password on host drive (which is Ubuntu also).
so to sum it up, I want to be able to change the password on USB drive Ubuntu NOT the host pc.
if this has already been addressed elsewhere, please point me to it, been trying for a week now.
Thanks

If you boot from the USB-drive(?) then you should have the option to also run "Recovery mode" from it.
Hit ESC once as the machine's boot procedure starts, just as it is displaying the UEFI/BIOS texts; and the "grub bootloader" -menu should appear... if you cannot get that to work; hold (either?) one of the SHIFT keys down as the boot procedure starts, the effect should be the same.
In the menu find

Advanced options
Recovery mode
select "fsck", "network" and "root" options in the last menu...
where the last will require a second enter to leave you at the bash prompt as the root user.

# ls -l /home - is likely to display the user names available
(each user has a USERNAME folder).
# passwd USERNAME - should trigger password setting for that user.
# reboot - to restart.

Generally you could just plug the stick into a Linux machine, mount the file system and use chroot into the mounted folder with the root user.
From there just passwd should work.
I haven't tested this jet, but that's what I would try.

Change Password
Is your USB Live Install, Persistent Install, or Full Install?
You can not change the password on a Live
Install.
For a Persistent Install or Full Install go to Settings/User.
